# Get woocommerce carts total amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, coupon

I am trying to apply a discount to a carts total price, but I can only do it to the item base price and not the over all price. I Googled and came across [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115441) post in the 
wordpress stackoverflow:

> $amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '',
>   $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) ); The preg_replace eliminates
>   everything but decimal characters and colons.
>
> Should you care to do math with it, the floatval converts the value
>   from a string to a numeric one.

I tried adding:

```
$amount2 = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
```

and changing

```
$discount = round( (($discounting_amount / 100 ) *  $this->amount)*-1, WC()->cart->dp);
```

to

```
$discount = round( (($discounting_amount / 100 ) *  $amount2)*-1, WC()->cart->dp);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart_total() on a non-object in...
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to call the global variable to ensure that it gets the correct values.

If you add

```
 global $woocommerce;
```

just before

```
 $amount2 = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
```

that should solve your problem.

Comment: For some countries you have to consider the comma too, try this `'#[^\d.,]#'`

Comment: `WC()->cart->get_cart_total()` did the trick without having to call the global $woocommerce

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

```
WC()->cart->cart_contents_total
```

The function get_cart_total uses wc_price function thas converts cart_contents_total to currency.

Comment: Use WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); to get Float from "cart_contents_total" property.

Answer (score 22):

This also work nicelly.

**`WC()->cart->total`**

Comment: This automatically includes the shipping

Comment: Also, it works if someone wants to get the cart total only in number (without HTML).

Answer (score 20):

As of late 2018, the best way is to use `get_cart_contents_total()`. This is the total of items in the cart after discounts.

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); // Float
```

Other methods are available for more specific needs, just have a look at [the docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_totals).

Comment: Yep this is a good one, like you said, after discounts and returns float. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This works perfectly and removes currency symbol:

```
     $woocommerce->cart->total;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
global $woocommerce;
    $amount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total+$woocommerce->cart->tax_total;
```

You can also convert $amount in float value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

REPUESTA FINAL

```
global $woocommerce;
  
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  
if ( $order ) {
$order->get_id();
$order->get_order_key();
$order->get_formatted_order_total();
$order->get_cart_tax();
$order->get_currency();
$order->get_discount_tax();
$order->get_discount_to_display();
$order->get_discount_total();
$order->get_fees();
$order->get_formatted_line_subtotal();
$order->get_shipping_tax();
$order->get_shipping_total();
$order->get_subtotal();
$order->get_subtotal_to_display();
$order->get_tax_location();
$order->get_tax_totals();
$order->get_taxes();
$order->get_total();
$order->get_total_discount();
$order->get_total_tax();
$order->get_total_refunded();
$order->get_total_tax_refunded();
$order->get_total_shipping_refunded();
$order->get_item_count_refunded();
$order->get_total_qty_refunded();
$order->get_qty_refunded_for_item();
$order->get_total_refunded_for_item();
$order->get_tax_refunded_for_item();
$order->get_total_tax_refunded_by_rate_id();
$order->get_remaining_refund_amount();
  
// recorder ITEMs 

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
   $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
   $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
   $product = $item->get_product();
   $name = $item->get_name();
   $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
   $subtotal = $item->get_subtotal();
   $total = $item->get_total();
   $tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
   $taxclass = $item->get_tax_class();
   $taxstat = $item->get_tax_status();
   $allmeta = $item->get_meta_data();
   $somemeta = $item->get_meta( '_whatever', true );
   $type = $item->get_type();
}

$order->get_items_key();
$order->get_items_tax_classes();
$order->get_item_count();
$order->get_item_total();
$order->get_downloadable_items();
$order->get_line_subtotal();
$order->get_line_tax();
$order->get_line_total();
$order->get_shipping_method();
$order->get_shipping_methods();
$order->get_shipping_to_display();
$order->get_date_created();
$order->get_date_modified();
$order->get_date_completed();
$order->get_date_paid();
$order->get_customer_id();
$order->get_user_id();
$order->get_user();
$order->get_customer_ip_address();
$order->get_customer_user_agent();
$order->get_created_via();
$order->get_customer_note();
$order->get_address_prop();
$order->get_billing_first_name();
$order->get_billing_last_name();
$order->get_billing_company();
$order->get_billing_address_1();
$order->get_billing_address_2();
$order->get_billing_city();
$order->get_billing_state();
$order->get_billing_postcode();
$order->get_billing_country();
$order->get_billing_email();
$order->get_billing_phone();
$order->get_shipping_first_name();
$order->get_shipping_last_name();
$order->get_shipping_company();
$order->get_shipping_address_1();
$order->get_shipping_address_2();
$order->get_shipping_city();
$order->get_shipping_state();
$order->get_shipping_postcode();
$order->get_shipping_country();
$order->get_address();
$order->get_shipping_address_map_url();
$order->get_formatted_billing_full_name();
$order->get_formatted_shipping_full_name();
$order->get_formatted_billing_address();
$order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
  
// Get Order Payment Details
$order->get_payment_method();
$order->get_payment_method_title();
$order->get_transaction_id();
  
// Get Order URLs
$order->get_checkout_payment_url();
$order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
$order->get_cancel_order_url();
$order->get_cancel_order_url_raw();
$order->get_cancel_endpoint();
$order->get_view_order_url();
$order->get_edit_order_url();
$order->get_status();

}

// para obtener el simbolo '$'

get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()
```

Answer (score 3):

To show the carts total including tax and discounts use this

> ```
> $ordertotal = wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_total() );
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
WC()->cart->subtotal; 
this function use for get total without currency
WC()->cart->get_total();
this function use for get total with currency
```

Answer (score 1):

Function get_cart_contents_total() gives the  total of items in the cart, but after discounts. Depending on the tax settings you might have to add taxes. Something lie this:

```
$cart_total_price = wc_prices_include_tax() ? WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax() : WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code outputs formatted price with currency

```
wc_price( WC()->cart->cart_contents_total); // Output example $118,000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$totalamount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; 

echo $totalamount;
```

Comment: You should provide a bit detailed explanation for your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_cart_contents_total/)

> WC_Cart::get_cart_contents_total() – Gets cart total. This is the total of items in the cart, but after discounts. Subtotal is before discounts.

So, if you want with discounts, you may call

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total()
```

If you want without the discount, you may call

```
WC()->cart->get_subtotal()
```

There is another useful function for getting shipping

```
WC()->cart->get_shipping_total()
```

So, the total amount should be

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_shipping_total()
```

Also you may also want to include tax in the calculation as pointed out by @geza-goz